# Any PDF reader with continuous horizontal scrolling?

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, reading, touchscreen

I have a specific use case for PDF reading, which I'm struggling to fulfill.

I frequently read magazines on my (Windows/Linux) tablet (hybrid, actually). Since the screen is relatively small (16:9 11.6") for A4 display, I've been trying which setup would make reading least uncomfortable.

I've found that keeping the tablet in portrait mode, zoom it a bit, and scroll the pages horizontally with touch input, full screen, and continuous mode.

One PDF reader, SumatraPDF, has actually this functionality, although it's very quirky: it's easy to flip page instead of scrolling horizontally, and when flipping page, it goes to the right end of the following page, instead of the beginning.

I've tried a few other ones, but they're not usable at all, in this way, namely Adobe Reader 11 And Foxit Reader, which don't zoom when in Full Screen mode or don't allow horizontal continuous scrolling.

Is there any PDF reader which can accomplish this? Any O/S would be fine (except Apple ones), as long as it:

- supports zoom and horizontal continuous scrolling also in full screen
- has touch interface

Comment: helo! i was looking for the same needs. In my iPad mini now i can read very confortably book scans with an app named "Documents" try its pdf reading feauture :)

Comment: *Any O/S would be fine (except Mac)*

Comment: @JanDoggen Mac != iPad, not even mini-= :) But I agree to interpret Marcus' statement that way.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I've updated it to be clearer ("Apple ones").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xodo](https://www.xodo.com/) fulfills the requirements; it supports:

- zoom
- two-pages horizontal scrolling (which matches reading from a magazine)
- is touch based.

It has some minor rough edges (my major complaint being not supporting automatic vertical fit), but does the job well.

Comment: Xodo works, but is there something that has a local app for Windows?

Comment: You refer to something with an installer? There isn't for Xodo, however, for me doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

[EBookDroid](https://github.com/nivieru/ebookdroid) fulfills the requirements. It supports:

- zoom
- touch
- view books in either vertical scroll, horizontal scroll, smart facing pages, or smart scroll.
- split pages to adapt reading two-column pages vertically.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF reader that comes built into Zotero has this feature and I really like it. Zotero is also a great way to organise your documents.

Comment: Please provide more information including a link to its home page